# Vuforia Videoplayback flipped and mirrored video

Tags: android, video, vuforia

I'm working with Vuforia SDK (Android), with Videoplayback sample, and I sometimes get a bug: inverted, mirrored video on the target. Here's screen (number 2):

[image]

Comment: Problem solved, by trick)
added  float videoQuadTextureCoords[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, }; from iOS code, then added new Target, and it's work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing the

```
float videoQuadTextureCoordsTransformed[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, };
```

to

```
float videoQuadTextureCoords[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, };
```

Comment: wait a second... in the setVideoDimensions it uses both... you *just* use videoQuadTextureCoords[] ?

Comment: Please help me to solve the issue.. in my case there are certain no. of targets . only some cases the video is inverted . after that all the videos is playing inverted

Comment: @Somasundaram NP